# How to deal file upload error with XmlHttpRequest and asp.net mvc?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, upload

for simplicity:

client:

```
var xrh = new XmlHttpRequest();
...
xrh.onerror = on_upload_error;
xrh.send(...)
```

server:

```
public class file_transfer
{
    [HttpPost]
    public void Upload(HttpPostedFileBase[] files_to_upload)
    {
        ...
        if (succeeded)
        {
            // what should I to to let the client know the success? in onload
        }
        else
        {
            // what should I to to let the client know the failaure? maybe in onerror
        }
    }
}
```

what should I to to let the client know the success? in onload?

what should I to to let the client know the failaure? maybe in onerror?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return http success/failed code to client:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase[] files_to_upload)
{
    ...
    if (succeeded)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(200);
    }
    else
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(400);
    }
}
```

Comment: And you need follow the asp.net mvc convention, the controller class must ending with 'Controller'. Such as AccountController

Comment: Does these json results bind to onerror and onload in the XmlHttpRequest?

Comment: Yes, it should be UploadController(...) instead of Upload(...)

Comment: If you want bind onerror and onload, json result is inproper. In this case,you can use HttpStatusCodeReuslt, when success return 2xx code, when failed return 4xx or 5xx code

Comment: Thank you. I want to see the error message, so want to return a JsonResult, but how to fetch the JsonResult on the client side? the on on_load(evt) is called, but evt.status is not defined.

Comment: JSON.parse(xhr.responseText); works, but xhr is global, is it possible to make it local through the parameter in on_load(evt)?

Comment: solved by using 'this.responseText', js and jquery both has 'this' keyword, a little confusing then. Thank you very much.